# Unable to upload image to firebase storage with firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

here is my code:-

```
exports.uploadImage = (req, res) => {

    const BusBoy = require('busboy');
    const path = require('path');
    const os = require('os');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });

    let imageFileName;
    let imageToBeUploaded = {};

    busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {

        const imageExtension = filename.split('.')[filename.split('.').length - 1];
        imageFileName = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 100000000000)}.${imageExtension}`;
        const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName);
        imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));

    });

    busboy.on('finish', () => {

        console.log('Busboy on started');    

        //code breaks here    
        admin.storage().bucket().upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
            resumable: false,
            metadata: {
                metadata: {
                    contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype
                }
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            const imageUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o/${imageFileName}?alt=media`;
            console.log('logging image url' + imageUrl);
            return db.doc(`/users/${req.user.handle}`).update({ imageUrl })
        })
        .then(() => {
            return res.json({ message: 'Image uploaded successfully' });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
        })
    });
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
}
```

I have mentioned where my code is breaking in a comment and the error I am getting is `Error: Cannot parse response as JSON: Not Found`
`message: 'Cannot parse response as JSON: Not Found'`

The error message says cannot parse response as `JSON`. Does that mean the response from firebase is not JSON? I have a token in the header of the request and an image in the body as form-data. I really have not clue what wrong, please help

Comment: Have you tried making this into a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (e.g. one that just looks at the storage calls in isolation?  In particular, since you are mixing both firebase-style (e.g. using the admin API) and non-firebase-style (your cloud function declaration) it'd be helpful to have something complete to reproduce.

Comment: Another observation -- rather than piping the input file to the filesystem, and then reading it back out via `upload()` you could instead use the GCS [createWriteStream](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.5.x/File) API and pipe it directly through.

Comment: @robsiemb actually I am following an online tutorial and the code is from that tutorial so I dont have a good idea of what style I am following

Comment: @robsiemb can you please tell what do you mean pipping?

Comment: piping: the call to `file.pipe()` writing to a stream.  There's no reason to write to the filesystem and then read back from the filesystem when you can just write directly to a stream that goes to GCS via the `createWriteStream` api.

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately can't identify the JSON parsing error, so I've instead rewritten the code to be more streamlined as [@robsiemb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3399890) eluded to.

Your `uploadImage` function appears to be configured as some middleware, so I have done the same below. This code will stream the uploaded data straight to Cloud Storage under a unique file name as generated from [`Reference.push().key`](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) to prevent conflicts.

In the code below,

- The uploaded file will be stored at a location similar to: `userData/someUserId/images/-JhLeOlGIEjaIOFHR0xd.png`
- The image's raw URL is not stored in the database because unless the file object or containing bucket is made public it will require a [signed URL](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl) which can only last up to 7 days (see below).
- More than one file can be accepted and uploaded. If this is undesired, configure the [limits for the `BusBoy` instance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy#busboy-methods).
- Basic error handling for non-POST requests and missing file entries was added.

```js
// import Firebase libraries & initialize
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(); // initializes from environment variables

// import required modules
const BusBoy = require('busboy');

exports.uploadImage = (req, res) => {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
      res.sendStatus(405); // 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
      return;
    }

    let busboy = new BusBoy({headers: req.headers}); // add {limits: {files: 1}} to limit to only a single file upload
    let bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
    let db = admin.firestore();

    let storageFilepath;
    let storageFile;

    // Note: Currently only the last file is saved to `/users/${req.user.handle}`
    busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
        let fileext = filename.match(/\.[0-9a-z]+$/i)[0];

        storageFilepath = `userData/${req.user.handle}/images/` + getUniqueName() + fileext;
        storageFile = bucket.file(storageFilepath);

        file.pipe(storageFile.createWriteStream({ gzip: true }));
    })
    .on('finish', () => {
      if (!storageFile) {
        res.status(400).json({error: 'expected file'}); // 400 BAD_REQUEST
        return;
      }

      db.doc(`/users/${req.user.handle}`).update({ imagePath: storageFilepath })
        .then(() => {
            res.status(201).json({ message: 'Image uploaded successfully' }); // 201 CREATED
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).json({ error: err.code }); // 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        });
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });

    req.pipe(busboy);
});

function getUniqueName() {
  // push() without arguments returns a ThennableReference, which we'll abuse for it's key generation
  return admin.database().ref().push().key;
}
```

If you did want the uploaded image to be publicly accessible, you could use the following `.on('finish', ...)` handler that adds in the [`File.makePublic()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#makePublic) function:

```js
.on('finish', () => {
  if (!storageFile) {
    res.status(400).json({error: 'expected file'}); // 400 BAD_REQUEST
    return;
  }

  storageFile.makePublic()
    .then(() => {
      return db.doc(`/users/${req.user.handle}`).update({
          imagePath: storageFilepath,
          imageUrl: `https://storage.googleapis.com/${config.storageBucket}/${storageFilepath}`
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'Image uploaded successfully' }); // 201 CREATED
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err.code }); // 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the issue!

Essentially - you need to set up your Google Application Credentials. Go into firebase and look into your settings. You need to set up the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS so that firebase has your credentials when you access these files.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=1 for more information.

After you've done that, check the security settings in firebase, in every area you're dealing with. This should solve the problem (it's definitely a security issue and not your code).

This was the tutorial in question as well for those looking on . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_u6P5k0vP0&t=7661s .

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was wrong bucket Id configured - after correcting that i was able to upload file

Answer (score 0):

check the storage configuration under Firebase console >> Storage >> (tab) rules,
this is the default config, change the flag to true:

```
rules_version = '2';
 
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
  match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
   }
  }
}
```